# Передача фильтра между вьюшками cxgrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Нужно передать фильтр grTableView1 в grTableView2. фильтр используется стандартный который есть в cxgride.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как-то так :

```
grTableView2.DataController.Filter.AssignItems(grTableView1.DataController.Filter, false);
```